# SwiftUI Picker in WatchOS throws Scrollview-Error when using Digital Crown

Tags: xcode, swiftui, watchos, swiftui-picker

The following WatchOs App example is very short, but already not functioning as it is expected, when using Digital Crown (full code):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
   
   let array = ["One","Two","Three","Four"]
   @State var selection = "One"
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Array", selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(array, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following 2 errors are thrown, when using Digital Crown for scrolling:
[image: Xcode errors: ScrollView contentOffset + NSOSStatusErrorDomain]

1. ScrollView contentOffset binding has been read; this will cause grossly inefficient view performance as the ScrollView's content will be updated whenever its contentOffset changes. Read the contentOffset binding in a view that is not parented between the creator of the binding and the ScrollView to avoid this.
2. Error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-536870187 "(null)"

Unsuccessfully tested on real device (Apple Watch 8, 45mm, watchOS 10.3) and Xcode 15.2.

Any help appreciated. Thanks a lot.